# Parallax effect with stellar.js - whitespace appears after resizing

Tags: html, css, parallax

I'm trying to implement parallax effect on one page site with [stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) plugin. What I want is that every slide has 100% height. When I load page everything works fine, but if I resize browser strange white areas appears after slide with image background.

Here is my markup. Only page3 should have parallax effect.

```
<body>
<div id="header">Testing</div>
<div id="page1" class="page"></div>
<div id="page2" class="page"></div>
<div id="page3" class="page" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"></div>
<div id="page4" class="page"></div>
</body>
```

Here is css rules:

```
html,body{
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.page{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#page1{background-color: red;}
#page2{background-color: greenyellow;}
#page3 {
background-image:url(images/firstBG.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#page4{background-color: yellow;}

#header {position: fixed; background-color: gainsboro; height: 30px; width: 100%;}
```

Here is my example [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KoulSlou/RFrH2/)

What can be a cause of the problem?

UPD:

My example after removing background-repeat: no-repeat [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/KoulSlou/RFrH2/)

Comment: try removing background-repeat: no-repeat; for #page3

Comment: @Kishore I tried to remove 'no-repeat' property and now after resizing you can see that image is repeated in y-coordinate. It doesn't look very well. I believe there is some problem with stellar configuration like data-stellar-background-ratio, data-stellar-vertical-offset...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old article, but I thought I would post my solutions incase it helps others... I was able to solve this issue by setting the horizontalScrolling property to false, responsive property to true as well as setting the verticalOffset property to 0:

$.stellar({
        horizontalScrolling: false,
        responsive: true,
        verticalOffset: 0
    });

Comment: This worked for me. Tried all other suggestions but it seems the responsive:true parameter was the actual fix for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. If you set "responsive" property to true there will be no whitespaces after resizing:

```
$.stellar({responsive:true})
```

Here is a link to new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KoulSlou/RFrH2/)